# Jquery Countdown plugin does not start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use jquery Countdown plugin but when i put 12 days Countdown then it not start .I can not understand how to do it.I try to search google but i can not find any answer. I need To complete the project soon please some one help me to do it."I can not insert code because it up to 30000 that the site not support.That reason i insert some screenshot."

Demo here..

**Website looks like this:**

[image]

**I only change this line on jquery**

[image]

**plugin name jquery countdown.**

Comment: Hello, please post your code directly here rather than linking to the image.

Answer (score 0):

See the example on the jquery countdown website: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

```
 <div id="getting-started"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#getting-started")
   .countdown("2016/01/01", function(event) {
     $(this).text(
       event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
     );
   });
 </script>
```

You can put a date there. Just calculate the date in 12 days and init the counter with it.